# Ubuntu 14.04 runs slow on newish, fast laptop

Tags: 14.04

I have a computer with 8GB of RAM, an Intel i5 processor, and 750GB hard drive.

It previously ran Windows 8, but Ubuntu 14.04 runs sooooo slow.

I had installed linux mint 16 a while ago and that works fine but now that 17 has come out a few of the programs have become outdated.

Comment: Can you give any more details? What it is you experience with this slowness? I kind of is about to start a thread on my own on the subject, a laptop with i7, 16gb ram, 256gb ssd, moving between workspaces feels laggy. Running intel 4600 gfx with "latest drivers". My older laptop, i5 16gb and older intel built-in gfx was running smoothly on 12.04.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I assume you meant `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Comment: Check which OpenGL graphics you are running: `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` and then `glxinfo | grep renderer`

Comment: @CharlesGreen: This is what I got,
`    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile `

Comment: @mattias The last line indicates that you are using hardware GPU.  Is your computer consistantly slow at everything, or slow at specific times and tasks?  I'm on Ubuntu-Gnome 14.10, i7, 8GB laptop, 1 TB HDD.  There's a lot that I've done to 'tweak' performance.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: I would say constantly at certain tasks (moving between workspaces for one). I have a colleague (yes it's my work computer) whose computer has identical setup but is much more smooth and quick shifting between workspaces. I use dual 24" monitors, but if i disconnect them to use only laptop monitor it's still slow when switching between workspaces.

Comment: For me, one of the realizations was that I have a really slow disk system (laptop) and Linux uses a lot of RAM for cache.  When the cache becomes dirty, the disk becomes busy-ish and really starts to bog down system performance - changing cache parameters has really helped my system, although I find I still need to clear my cache when I'm really busy.  Parameters I'm using:  `vm.dirty_background_ratio = 1` `vm.dirty_ratio = 80`  I have swappiness up at 60 right now, but will probably lower it soon.

Comment: Also running `elevator=cfq` in the `GRUB_COMMAND` lines to set the default disk scheduler to something I can live with better.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Well I have a SSD disk. I guess I can do some benchmarking of it, to see if there are any problems with it, but I doubt that is the bottleneck. I suspect it's something in my current Ubuntu installation that makes the system behave _laggyish_.

Comment: SSD wants `elevator=noop`, I believe.  You might check the cache issue, you can force the cache clear by `sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"`